# Android The following classes could not be instantiated: - com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView (Open Class, Show Exception)

Tags: java, android, xml, google-play-services

Im trying to put ads on my app, but when I put the ads on the xml, i get this error:

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView (Open Class, Show Exception)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE
```

I am using AndroidStudio and Im doing everything according to the samples on the sdk - /extras/google-play-services/samples/ads.

Can anyone help me please?

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
android:background="@drawable/fartpic"
>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/copy_right" />
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/fart_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".FartActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
</application>
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pachu.fartsounds"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
}
```

Comment: Did you try the suggestion in the error message?  We're not here to troubleshoot your code for you... We're here to help you with the troubleshooting that you've already performed.  Which line of code is producing the error?

Comment: didnt understand what to do and where to use it

Comment: You usually get this error in the editor preview in Android studio, when a custom view has not been properly designed for it (does not use View.isInEditMode() as the error suggests). As you did not write that custom view (adView) you should not be fixing it. if all the above applies, this warning is safe to ignore. just run your code and there shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Are you able to `Open Class` or `Show Exception`? Add the detailed exception if you can.

Comment: Thanks for the help, its what @Oren said, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when trying to preview the custom view AdView in the Intellij Community Edition IDE. There appears to be a bug or at least "preview-unfriendly" code in the 
latest version of the AdView class that is causing this problem so I down-graded the dependency 
in my gradle file (Intellij project-based) to use version 4.x like this:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.+'
```

specifically, I changed the dependencies section of my gradle file to look like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.+'
}
```

---

I don't think this is the proper solution (I'm going to try to file a bug report if one hasn't been filed already) since Google now requires the use of the "latest" Google Play Service SDK as of 8/31/2014.